# Get the value of Esim eid using C++/winRT

Tags: c++-winrt

I am trying to fetch the Esim id using the below code, i have followed the instruction provided in the below comment
"ESim is not static property, you can't access it with above code, for getting ESim instance, you need use ESimManagerto make eWatcher, then get ESim in EWatcher_Added event args."

But the below code is crashing!!

```
auto esimwatcher = ESimManager::TryCreateESimWatcher()
auto esimadd = esimwatcher.Added(Added_esim);
extern HANDLE Added_esim(winrt::Windows::Networking::NetworkOperators::ESimWatcher const& 
sender, winrt::Windows::Networking::NetworkOperators::ESimAddedEventArgs const& args)
{
DebugMessage(DEBUG_LEVEL_INFO, TRUE, L"\t ESIMWATCHER EVENT %ls\n",args.ESim().Eid().c_str());
return(S_OK);
}
```

Comment: Where is it crashing?

Comment: The code doesn't compile. Please show a [mcve], and make sure to include a sufficiently complete error description.

Comment: we are able to create the Esimwatcher from the Esimmanager, but when we try to added to Esimwatcher the code is getting crash.

Comment: Does your process get terminated due to an unhandled C++ exception? Do you get an SEH exception? Something else? Please be specific about the observed behavior.

Comment: My guess is that you in fact did *not* create the ESimWatcher from the ESimManager. The `esimwatcher` variable is probably null, so the call to `Added()` will crash. [The documentation for TryCreateESimWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.networkoperators.esimmanager.trycreateesimwatcher?view=winrt-22000) says that it returns " null if the caller's user security identifier (SID) is not authorized by the Windows service that handles eSIM-related operation requests.". I suspect that the caller's SID is not authorized to perform eSIM operations.

Comment: Yes, as you said the esimwatcher variable is getting "null". Could you please suggest how to authorize the SID for windows service- that handles esim-relates operations.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.networkoperators.esimmanager.trycreateesimwatcher) explains this: *"This functionality is available only to mobile operator apps and UWP apps given privileged access by mobile network operators."*

Comment: we are trying on UWP apps which having the access by mobile operator.

Comment: when i try to get the status for esimwatcher, the command prompt is getting exited   '''auto esimwatcher = ESimManager::TryCreateESimWatcher(); //creating the esim watcher
 wprintf(L"\n inside the Esim events%ws, \n\t", esimwatcher);     //printing the esimwatcer
 exitedwprintf(L"\n inside the radiostatechange events %d, \n", esimwatcher.Status())''' //getting the status of esimwatcher

Comment: Also from the documentation for TryCreateESimWatcher, in the big purple box: "If you want to use this API and publish your app to the Microsoft Store, then you'll need to request special approval to use the custom capability Microsoft.eSIMManagement_8wekyb3d8bbwe. For more info, see [Custom capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#custom-capabilities)." The documentation notes that custom capability enforcement is disabled in Developer Mode.